# User authentication in MVC using LDAP

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, ldap

I want to do the user authentication using LDAP(Lightweight Directory Access Protocol).I dont have any knowledge about this.still I have managed to write some code for this,but the problem is that when i am signing with the Username and Password present at my Databse i.e User table I ma not able to login.But when I am using LDAP's Username and password i am able to login into the application
My code goes as follows:

```
public ActionResult Login(APPUser model, string returnUrl)
  {
    try
      {
       using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"10.0.0.100"))
             {
               if (pc.ValidateCredentials(model.UserID, model.Password))
                  {
                     FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserID, false);
                     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                   }
              }
              if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserID, model.Password))
                {
                  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserID, false);
                        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                        {
                            return Redirect(returnUrl);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                        }
                }
                 else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login failed");
                    }
                }
     catch
        {
        }
          //GetErrorsFromModelState();
                return View(model);
```

}

and **Web.Config**

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://"XXXXXXX":389/DC=XXXX,DC=XXX" />
</connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Auth/Login" timeout="2880"/>
        </authentication>
 <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
       <clear />
         <add name="ADMembershipProvider" 
                 type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                 connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
                  connectionProtection="Secure"
                  connectionUsername="admin"
                  connectionPassword="admin234"
                  attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
                  enableSearchMethods="false" />
          </providers>
</membership>
```

Please try to help me out.

Comment: I am confused here. You are saying that you are trying to authenticate with LDAP. Which you later say is working! So what exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: Actually I dont know the process how does this LDAP works?If I explain u I do have a table called as User that has username and password and I do have a Active directory Username and password.If I am entering the Username and Password from the User table it does not allow to login and if I use Active directory's Username and password I am able to login

Comment: In my knowledge the Active directory Username and password that i am having it must be used for accessing the AD(Active directory) and the username and password that I want to put in from User Table that must be Authenticated using LDAP.

Comment: try to help me out as I am very new to this approach

Comment: I used something similar in the past. If you are using LDAP it doesnt need to access your Database at all to Authenticate as it uses the Active Directory. So you do not need to store the username and passwords at all.

Comment: Ok..So LDAP what username and password authenticates?Is it the Username and password thats stored into the Active Directory?and if yes then there is no need of having this table.do u have any Sample code or Document?

Comment: I went through multiple sites and documents but not able to under stand the procedure..

Comment: I don't have the code to hand no. It uses the Active Directory username and password so unless you are doing anything else with that table then you don't need it!

Comment: Well...I will have to find my way..but thanks alot for ur Response and time..may be on my right track..Thanks for guiding me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AD (Active Directory) is a directory service provider (a system that provides authentication, directory, policy, and other services in a Windows environment).

LDAP (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) is a protocol designed for directory service providers for querying and modifying items in directory service providers like AD, which supports a form of LDAP.

In other words, you use LDAP for retrieving information from AD.

Now, if you need to implement an authentication of intranet users against Windows domain (AD) then you need to read about [Integrated Windows Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647076.aspx). To enable it typically you need

- setup IIS for integrated windows authentication
- setup asp.net application

and optionally enable integrated windows authentication in IE. Read more [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1983202.aspx?ASP%20NET%204%200%20and%20LDAP%20Authentication%20on%20IIS%206)

Once done, user will be automatically logged in without entering his login name or password. You will be able to get his identity (User.Identity.Name) and other properties from AD.

This is a secure form of authentication which you can see when using SharePoint, Outlook Web Access or similar intranet applications.

Comment: Can i get any sample code to work with as this concept is very new to me?

Comment: Does LDAP authenticate username and password from the databse or only Active Directory Username and Password

Comment: When talking about Integrated Windows Authentication, your application does not need to have any database of users and their passwords. You even does not require to have any login form as all will go automatically. There is also no programming code required. If you are still in doubt about it, give more details on your requirements.

Comment: I am developing one application where User log in to the system using its Username and Password that has been saved into the database.but i want that the username and password must be authenticated using LDAP..

Comment: Still not clear why you need to enter login/password if it can be done without it. See example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx

Comment: bt here also a login page is created that is meant for feeding Username and password only..right?if this wud be wid MVC wud be better

Comment: Entering username and password (forms authentication) can be useful if you have multiple domains, extranet or something like this where user needs to enter credentials other than current identity. If it is not the case then use integrated Windows Authentication without login/password.